# as3 importing classes

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having problems with importing a class. I can make an instance of the class, but I can not use a public static member. When I put all the files in the same package I don't have any problems, but when I have to import I get this error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property MAIN_MENU through a reference with static type Class.

Here's the beginning of the main class:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

import classes.gameStates.MainMenuScreen;

public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
{
    private var mainMenuScreen:MainMenuScreen;

    public function DocumentClass()
    {
        displayMainMenu();
    }

    private function displayMainMenu():void
    {
        mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen();
        mainMenuScreen.x = 0;
        mainMenuScreen.y = 0;
        mainMenuScreen.addEventListener(MainMenuScreen.START_GAME, onStartGame);
        mainMenuScreen.addEventListener(MainMenuScreen.CREDITS, onCredits);
        addChild(mainMenuScreen);
    }
```

And this is the MainMenuScreen class

```
package classes.gameStates
{   
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Sprite
{   
    public static const START_GAME:String = "startGame";
    public static const CREDITS:String = "credits";

    public function MainMenuScreen()
    {
        startGameButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartGame);
        creditsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartCredits);
    }

    public function Destroy():void
    {
        startGameButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartGame);
        creditsButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartCredits);
    }

    private function onStartGame(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(MainMenuScreen.START_GAME));
    }

    private function onStartCredits(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(MainMenuScreen.CREDITS));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the lines around where you use MAIN_MENU ?

Comment: I get the same error for START_GAME and CREDITS. The errors are:                  error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property START_GAME through a reference with static type Class.                             error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property CREDITS through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: You are instantiating the MainMenuScreen within the constructor of the document class. This may be the root of the problem. Try to use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` and do the instantiation in a listener method.

Comment: I tried that. Why does it matter if I instantiate MainMenuScreen in the constructor, if I'm calling a static const?

Comment: The obvious question first: Did it work?

Comment: No, it did not work. I still got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

How can you make this work?? Or you did truncate your code already? Firstly, your buttons in MainMenuS aren't contstructed. Secondly, onStartGame and onCredit() is PRIVATE, DocumentClass has no way to access this.

Try to change its modifier first.

Comment: The onStartGame() and onStartCredits() are only used in the MainMenuScreen class. DocumentClass has its own onStartGame() and onCredits listeners. I just didn't show them. The buttons are instantiated in flash. The problem I'm getting is that the MainMenuScreen class is not being imported into DocumentClass even though I use import classes.gameStates.MainMenuScreen;